# Numpy: Is this the most efficient way to add a column of ones to a 1D vector?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In my Python script, I load a 1D vector from a `.dat` file. I want to use that vector as the first column in a matrix, where the second column is filled with 1s. This is how I did it:

```
x = np.loadtxt( 'x.dat' )
m = x.shape[0]
X = np.concatenate((x.reshape((m,1)), np.ones((m,1))), axis=1)
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Not really.  You have to make a new array, one way or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks perfectly reasonable to me. If you are really squeezing for performance you can try the following:

```
X = np.ones((m, 2))
X[:,0] = x
```

or:

```
X = np.empty((m, 2))
X[:,0] = x
X[:,1] = 1
```

I wouldn't be surprised if they're slower though.

However, I expect that most of your performance is not lost on adding an extra column, but instead on `np.loadtxt`. Consider changing your data format to `np.save`/`np.load`, which is much faster.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm not getting any performance issues, because the data set I'm working with is small. I'm just trying to get better with numpy.